# install4j DMG archive, setting permissions on additional files?

Tags: install4j, dmg

Is it possible to change the permissions of files that get added to the DMG volume created by install4j (via Media->macOS single bundle archive->Installer options->DMG options and files->Additional Files in DMG->"+"-> Regular file)?

I am adding a separately uninstall.app (to uninstall pre-install4j versions of the Application) but the added executable file the uninstall.app runs ends up not being executable! (I have to add all of the files under uninstall.app individually)

I have a workaround which is to include the uninstall.app as a separate File set which gets embedded within the Application.app/Contents/Resources/app folder, and then creating a symbolic link in the DMG down to that, but I'd prefer to have the whole uninstall.app separated -- it can be run directly from the DMG.

Suggestion: Allow setting permissions of the additional files (or just preserve permissions). Also a recursive "copy folder into DMG" would be good, or alternatively allow copying of an already defined File set into the DMG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions, I have added them to our issue tracker.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the permissions as of install4j 8.0.

---

**Update 2021-02-05**

This will be available in install4j 9.0.